Is there a way to autodetect User for systemctl service?
I have a QT project that is being launched by custom systemctl service on Ubuntu. The problem is that I need to edit my .service file each time I am trying to set up this stuff on new device.
For example, I set up program and launching service on one device with username orangepi and then on the second one with username firefly.
The .service unit file is following:
[Unit]
Description=Terminal Service

[Service]
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/home/$USER/soft/ProjectFolder/auto-restart.sh"
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
User=firefly   #    User=orangepi
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGINT

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I need edit User line to make this service work on device with another username. The question is how to let it know the username automatically?
Tried using User=$USER like in the terminal but it isn't working and also deleting the User line at all had no success.
P.S.
There is only one user on each device.
